# Populate Post Object field with selected value of taxonomy field ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, acfpro

I have 2 fields:

1. type taxonomy called "category"
2. type post object called "products"

What i want? populate the dropdown of "products" only with the "category" selected.

I'm trying this:

```
function filter_product_query( $args, $categorId ) {    
    
    $categorId = get_field('category_v1');
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'tax_query'      => array( array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
            'field'      => 'term_id',
            'terms'      => $categorId ,
        ) )
    );          
    return $args;
    
}
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/key=field_61e745e87a5a6', 'filter_product_query', 10, 4);
```

But doesn't work.

[Taxonomy field configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEnZp.png)

[Post object field configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPi5V.png)

Comment: You need to use `javascript` too, specifically you need to use `on change` event to listen for any changes on your drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this as well.

Now, to start with.  If the function isn't beign called, at all.  Then chances are, you're using the wrong hook.  There is also a hook called

Here are the ones that helped me
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-query/

and

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-taxonomy-result/

There are others.  Pay close attention to the hook text as its probably not a post_object.

If the function you're using is getting called, then you got to follow the steps here as I'm guessing its related to this issue,

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/send-additional-field-for-ajax-update-event-on-selecttaxonomy/

and possibly this one as well, that references the above.
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/trouble-with-acffieldspost_objectquery-filter/